# Solve this differential equation (can't do the integral in the last step)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\displaystyle{%
{\rm y}'\left(x\right)
=
\sqrt{x\,}\,\, {\rm y}\left(x\right) + {{\rm e}^{x} \over \sqrt{x\,}\,}\,,
\qquad{\rm y}\left(0\right) = 2}$

I don't know how to do the integral in the last step.

Comment: What integral are you left with?

Comment: What integrating factor did you get?

Comment: The integral is non-elementary.  If this is homework, leave it in the form of an integral.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you.

Answer (score 4):

(EDITED): 
It looks like there's a "closed-form" solution to the differential equation in terms of the Heun T function and its derivative: in Maple's notation
$$y(x) = {\frac {3^{1/3} {2}^{2/3}{{\rm e}^x} {\it HeunT}
 \left( 0,-3,-{2}^{2/3}3^{1/3}/4,{3}^{2/3}2^{1/3}
 \left( 2\,\sqrt {x}-1 \right)/6  \right) }{{\it HeunTPrime}  \left( 0,-3,-{2}^{2/3}3^{1/3}/4,-{3}^{2/3}2^{1/3}
 /6  \right) }}
$$
This particular solution doesn't satisfy the initial condition: you must add an appropriate solution of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: +1 Everyday one learn something new and unheard of. I start to wonder whether there are infinitely many special functions.

Answer (score 3):

The integrating factor is $$\mu(x)=e^{-\int\sqrt x~dx}=e^{-\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}}$$ and you need to evaluate the integral $$\int\frac{e^{-\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}+x}}{\sqrt x}~dx,$$ but unfortunetley, it is not possible to do that by elementary techniques of integration, so you leave the integral as it stands (as proposed in comments).